# decomposing a value into powers of two

Tags: java

I need to implement a function which decomposes a value into powers of two using java.

> e.g: 14= 8 + 4 + 2

I need to find the powers of two which the value gets decomposed. For the above example I need  2,3,1 as outputs. How could I implement that?

Comment: Are you familiar with logarithms?

Comment: @user1118321 - logarithms are the wrong tool for this.

Comment: In a computer, integers are represented in two-complement which means they are already a sum of powers of two.  All you need to do is determine which bits in an integer are set.

Comment: @Sura the order doesn't matter. I need the values

Comment: you input is 14 and your output is 3,2,1 ?

Comment: It is a part of it. The main question was not to implement this. but in order to do the main part i should be able to do this

Comment: @TedHopp Not necessarily. If they're going to need to generalize it to other bases besides base 2 in the future, then it could be helpful to use logarithms instead of shifts.

Comment: @user1118321 - You're changing the problem, and there's no reason to expect that the base will be generalized. Over-generalization usually leads to very inefficient code. This is a great example--here's a problem that can be solved quickly and easily using bit operations, but by generalizing you end up using logarithms, which is horribly expensive by comparison.

Comment: @HannoBinder, it can very well be interpretation of Linux permissions :)

Comment: @msysmilu, yes, there are a million valid use cases for bit-pattern routines. The point is, someone working on an assignment to learn something should be given different answers than one who just wants to get the task done. - There used to be a "homework" tag here on SO, but it was removed.

Comment: you are right @HannoBinder; homework is, in general, more rigid when it comes to possible workarounds;

Comment: I'd rather say that with "homework", someone is seeking hints/advice on how to approach a problem by himself, rather than asking for a piece of code which he can just copy&paste. Hence, providing the best possible ready-to-use solution to a homework-related question is not always a *good* answer, in the sense that it does help the OP in his learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you usually use bit-wise operations, namely the shift (<<,>>,>>>) and the bit-wise and (&) operator, because the internal representation of integers in computers already is binary, which is what you need.

In binary representation each integer value is a composition of powers of 2: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...

So, 14 in decimal is in binary 1110: 8 + 4 + 2 + 0.

If you're after some nice, generic algorithm, you may want to start decomposing decimal numbers into their powers of 10 and from there on extend your solution to other bases, like 2.

Answer (score 9):

Take advantage of the binary representation that Java uses. I don't know what form you want the powers of 2 to take, but you can loop through the bits one at a time by shifting and bit-wise `&` with 1 to test each bit. Each 1 bit represents a power of 2 in the sum.

For instance:

```
List<Integer> powers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
n = . . .; // something > 0
int power = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    if ((n & 1) != 0) {
        powers.add(1 << power);
        // or, if you just need the exponents:
        // powers.add(power);
    }
    ++power;
    n >>>= 1;
}
```

Comment: All computers and almost all language support binary representation. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Pretty much, but this is a Java question specifically.

Comment: In that case I would use the special collection Java has for a set of bits. ;)

Comment: What is going on with the triple ">>>"? I'm trying to read up on this: arithmetic shifts, logical shifts?

Comment: @num3ric - That's a shift with zero-fill instead of sign-fill. (Since I'm assuming that the number is > 0, it could just as well have been `>>`. Force of habit. [Actually, `>>=`.])

Comment: I think he meant to use `n++;` or `n >>>= 1;`

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Oops. It was supposed to be `>>>= 1`. How embarassing Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @Fazlan - That's the number you want to decompose.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Actually, not all modern computers use binary. See the Wikipedia article [Decimal computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_computer). They aren't just relics of the old days.

Comment: @TedHopp It is supported by modern mainframes. I consider mainframes in general to be legacy designs/architectures. I should have said all micro-computers ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I probably misstated things in my last comment. My guess is that every modern decimal computer also supports binary representation. At least that's true of all the processors cited in the Wikipedia article (one of which is a microprocessor, by the way). I don't know too much about this area of computing, though.

Comment: Greater than `1073741824` returns null.

Comment: @fsi - Greater than 1073741824 doesn't fit into an `int`; you'd need to make `n` a `long`. I also don't see how my code could return `null`. (When I tried it with 1073741825, I got back the list [1, 1073741824].)

Comment: this [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25373/decompor-numero-imenso-em-javascript/25376#25376) in portuguese, instead of using bitwise, he modified to multiply and division.

Comment: @fsi - That was done because JavaScript's bitwise operators automatically convert their operands to 32-bit integers and that was something to be avoided. It isn't really relevant to the current question which is in Java and is already dealing with `int` values. Using bitwise operators is going to be a lot faster than using multiplication and division.

Comment: Ohhh, I confused with java and javascript ... that's right!

Answer (score 8):

As integers are already represented as powers of two and Java has a collections for a set of bits I would use these two.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(bitsSet(14));
}

public static BitSet bitsSet(long num) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        if (((num >>> i) & 1) != 0)
            bitSet.set(i);
    return bitSet;
}
```

prints

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply subtract 2 from the value and keep subtracting subsequent higher powers.

```
int x = 0;
int value = args[0];
for (i=0, (value - Math.pow(2, i)) >= 0, i++) {
    value = value - Math.pow(2, i);
    x++;
}
for (i=0, i<x, i++) {
    System.out.println("addent: " + Math.pow(2, i);
}
```