# Get correct numbers

Tags: javascript

Sorry for a poor title, but I cannot even name the problem properly, hence unable to search for a solution, I can only describe what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a list of engine types & their fuels.

```
export const engineTypes = {
  0: 'HYBRID',
  1: 'GASOLINE',
  2: 'GAS',
  4: 'DIESEL',
  8: 'ELECTRIC',
}


export const fuelTypes = {
  DIESEL: 'Diesel',
  GASOLINE: 'Gasoline',
  GAS: 'Gas',
  HYBRID: 'Hybrid',
  ELECTRIC: 'Electric',
}

export const getFuelTypeByEngineType = (type) => {
  const engine = engineTypes[type]
  if (engine) {
    return fuelTypes[engine]
  }

}
```

The idea is to pass a value like `getFuelTypeByEngineType(2)` to get 'GAS' returned, however, if I do something like `getFuelTypeByEngineType(9)` i should get ['GASOLINE', 'ELECTRIC'] back.

Meaning 9 is -> 8 (ELECTRIC) + 1 (GASOLINE)

How to achieve this? Please help!

Comment: Is that ```getFuelTypeByEngineType(1)``` returns ```['HYBRID', 'GASOLINE']```?

Comment: That's weird way to get an item with multiple engine type. What if there are multiple enum values which sum upto the number passed? What if there was a `6` in the `engineTypes` enum? A comma separated  argument like `getFuelTypeByEngineType("8,1")` and splitting at the comma to get all the values would be better.

Comment: There may be multiple combinations. What about that?

Comment: @SajeebAhamed in my example you only get a string back.

Comment: @adiga that is not weird, and is a very efficient way of storing combined values, this way you can have any combination of items with just a single number.

Comment: @D.Pardal Will check. thx

Comment: @adiga there won't be any "8.1"... Only values it will receive is 0, 1, 2, 4, 8 and a combination of these

Comment: Also, based on your logic... all engines will be hybrid, since when you decompose a value it will always have a remainder of 0 in the end. Do you mean to use in steps of `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...` (without the zero)

Comment: Why not change it to something like this `getFuelTypeByEngineType = (...types) =>  types.map(t => engineTypes[t]) `. Then you can call with any number of arguments `getFuelTypeByEngineType(8)` or `getFuelTypeByEngineType(1,4,8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you borrow one of the answers in the linked question on [decomposing an arbitrary number into bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298374/decomposing-a-value-into-results-of-powers-of-two), then all you need to do is to use `Array.prototype.map` to return an array of engine types whose key is present in the returned bit array.

Some catches tho:

- You should've use a key of `0`, since at the final decomposition step you will always end up with a remainder of 0. If you insist on that, then you will need to guard clause in your method, that returns `["HYBRID"]` if the value is `0`
- In the event that the key does not exist in `engineTypes`, you will get `undefined`. That can be easily circumvented by filtering the mapped array.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const engineTypes = {
  0: 'HYBRID',
  1: 'GASOLINE',
  2: 'GAS',
  4: 'DIESEL',
  8: 'ELECTRIC',
}

const fuelTypes = {
  DIESEL: 'Diesel',
  GASOLINE: 'Gasoline',
  GAS: 'Gas',
  HYBRID: 'Hybrid',
  ELECTRIC: 'Electric',
}

const getFuelTypeByEngineType = (type) => {
  if (type === 0) {
    return [engineTypes[type]];
  }
  
  return getBits(type)
    .map(t => {
      return engineTypes[t];
    })
    .filter(v => !!v);
}

const getBits = (value) => {
  let b = 1;
  const res = [];
  while (b <= value){
    if (b & value) res.push(b);
    b <<= 1;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(getFuelTypeByEngineType(0)); // ["HYBRID"]
console.log(getFuelTypeByEngineType(9)); // ["GASOLINE", "ELECTRIC"]
console.log(getFuelTypeByEngineType(64)); // []
```